# Opscode CHEF(11.12.8) - chef-client can't add env. var. to PATH

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables, chef-infra

I'm using chef-client(11.12.8) with windows nodes(Win Server 2012).

I install perforce client. To do so I launch in a CMD chef-client in order to execute my cookbook.

Perforce installation set in PATH the appropriate path to p4.exe.
But in the cmd where I launch chef-client command the PATH is not updated.
So after, in my cookbook when I try to execute the command 'p4 sync' in a windows_batch resource it fails.

Solutions I try,

1/
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Perforce 
in a windows_batch resource before launching a p4 sync command.
DID NOT WORK.

2/
Put the previous command in a batch.
DID NOT WORK.

3/
$env:Path = $env:Path + ";C:\Program Files\Perforce"
in a powershell_script resource before launching a p4 sync command.
DID NOT WORK.

Is there a way to do that ?
Instead of using:
C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe

THANKS

---

UPDATE_01

the code but i don't think it would help so much...

Install perforceClient

```
windows_package 'Perforce Client' do
  source 'PerforceClient_2014.1\\p4vinst64.exe'
  options '/s /v"/qn"'
  installer_type :custom
  action :install
end

...

windows_batch 'Perforce sync' do
  code <<-EOH
  p4 sync //APP/
  EOH
end
```

Here the p4 command is unknow from the cmd where I launch chef-client command.
I will have a look at the batch resource.
Thanks

Comment: Please show your recipe code and the output of a chef run. That said since 11.6 the [batch resource](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_batch.html) is recomended instead of windows_batch. Without a run log (with `-l debug` for completeness) no one can't help you. the execute you (maybe ?) use accept and environment attribute, it's where you should give an updated env, but without your code I can't make a real answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
windows_package 'Perforce Client' do
  source 'PerforceClient_2014.1\\p4vinst64.exe'
  options '/s /v"/qn"'
  installer_type :custom
  action :install
  notifies :run, "execute[PerforceSync]", :immediately
end

execute 'PerforceSync' do
 action :nothing
 command 'p4 sync //APP/'
 environment { "PATH": "#{ENV['PATH']};C:\Program Files\Perforce" }
end
```

No need to use a `windows_batch` resource to execute a single command.

I use action nothing in the execute resource to avoid executing it at each run and only notify it to run when the package is installed.

`windows_batch` or `batch` resource exist to transpose existing batches.
I'm sure you don't write a .bat or .cmd file to run a single command.

`execute` resource documentation is [HERE](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_execute.html)

Side note: you should consider adding a guard to any execute or batch resource if it is not driven by another resource, see [This](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_execute.html#guards) as a starting point.

Comment: Yep,
Thank you tensibai, that's what I need to do.
I didn't no about the execute resource ;) I'm a newbie in Chef.
I keep in mind to use guard in recipe.